# Serial communication protocol

Tags: serial, serial-bus

I want to learn about the raw serial communication protocol (The one that uses the Rx and Tx pins of a microcontroller).

I want to be able to send bits of data without using a microcontroller.

How would you go about to send the letter "a"  (I guess you send the ASCII character) but how do you do that??

Is there a predefined way the pins flash?

I want to know everything there is to know about the serial communication protocol.

It would be great if anybody sent me links to learn this in a very in depth way.

**further clarification**
Here's what I want to do..... I want to build a circuit (probably using a 555 timer and yes it's gonna be ridiculously slow) that will send the character "a" repeatedly.

Why am I doing this??? Well...by doing this I will get a a really good understanding about this whole serial communication thing

Comment: The simplest protocol is probably UART / USART (a standard that stands for Universal (a/s)ynchronous receiver-transmitter). - Setting it up with a 555 timer will take a **very very very long time** (very tedious). But once it's done it will most likely run very fast, if not too fast. You will probably only manage to get repetitive patterns, and one direction only. (No real communication, just some broadcasting from the 555 timer to everything else).

Comment: Your goals and methods don't align IMO. UART is very simple, and there really isn't much to learn. Trying to get a 555 timer to send out a repetitive pattern is going to be a huge PITA. In the end you learned how to make a 555 timer do something it wasn't intended to do, and nothing about serial communication. Your time is better spent reading some Wikipedia pages.

Comment: If you truly want to learn how the protocol works, then make it in VHDL/Verilog on an FPGA/CPLD. Or, implement it on a microcontroller in software in C / C++ / Assembler. Assembler will probably be easiest and best for you. If I want to learn how to drive a car, then the logical thing to do would be to drive a car, right? - Program the protocol where it's actually being used, right? What you are trying to do right now is learn how to bicycle by running around in a circle, because wheels are round, and that will somehow help you..... very little.

Comment: "I want to learn about" is not a question specific enough for the Stack Exchange format.  The information you seek is in plenty of existing writeups online, often for "bit banging" implementations where MCU's software toggle a GPIO pin, or for FPGAs.  Doing this with discrete logic will be hard - first start with a bit-bang software approach to verify your understanding of what the waveform needs to be.

Comment: @HarrySvensson thank you. I will keep this in mind :-)

Comment: @HarrySvensson yes, what I'm trying to do is actually learn the protocol by sending repetitive data. After that, I can program a microcontroller to simulate a serial connection from any pin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just a couple of pointers to help you.

Forget your 555 idea. Use something that can generate any byte value from 0 to 255. For your learning to be useful you will need to develop some micro-controller skills so you might as well start now.

[image]

*Figure 1. Basic principle of serial data transfer. One byte of data is transferred out one bit at a time, LSB (least significant bit) first.*

Be aware of the need for start and stop bits and how they are used to synchronise the receiving device clock for correct decoding.

[image: Timing diagram of 8 bit byte showing margin of error for clock]

*Figure 2. Receiver sampling points. Source: [Sangoma](https://www.sangoma.com/tutorials/sync_n_async/).*

The start bit is used to trigger the read cycle in the receiver. The receiver synchronises itself on the start bit and then waits 1.5 cycles to start sampling bits. Thereafter the bits are sampled at the baud rate. This initial delay means that even with a 5% clock error the receiver should still be within the bit timing for the last bit.

Since the start bit - shown low in Figure 2. - is identified by a falling edge then it must be preceded by a high and this is what the stop bit ensures. The alternative would be two start bits and no stop bits but it wouldn't change the total message length.

The linked article has some other points worth noting.

If you can make an RS232 transmitter you could monitor the data using a program such as PuTTY on a PC with serial interface or RS232-USB adaptor.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. This is exactly what I was looking for. you helped me ALOT. :-)

Answer (score -1):

To make it simple, invert your learning investigation.

Use a small MCU (Arduino perhaps) to continuously send an 'a' from a digital I/O port and try to build external logic to receive the character. You could start reading [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample).
You'll learn about baud rates, start and stop bits and the ASCII code. ....Google those terms and you'll learn most of what you need.

Comment: While studying the waveform is a good ideas, this is both **not an answer to the question**, and **bad, diversionary advice**.  Receiving an asynchronous serial stream is a far, far more complicated task than generating one - it is pretty much always accomplished by oversampling.

Comment: @ChrisStratton. I disagree, since when sending a continuous stream of characters  it is difficult to get correct baud rates that can be received. The OP would end up using what to Rx?? ...an Arduino? ...you are back to using programming. When you use a completed sender, you can look at the waveform on a CRO, you can complete logic to sync in a start bit, to derive parity and stop bits, and you can eventually do the serial to parallel conversion for a character. You can also send stream of different characters easily ("Quick Brown Fox...") which would be an unlikely project for a newbie.

Comment: You've obviously never actually implemented any of this.  If you had, you'd realize that sending is an order of magnitude simpler than receiving.  It doesn't seem you really have any understanding of asynchronous receiver implementations *at all*.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Now you are being both obnoxious and personal. Not nice on a group like this. Not only have I implemented both Tx and Rx, but have been exposed to this before the time of UARTs. I'm happy to add circuits if you do the same and let the members decide.  ....and I didn't say which (Rx or TX) was simpler..... I said it's easier to work with an Rx, and this is especially so when you have confidence in the Tx.  I also note the OP suggests he will use an MCU Tx  eventually.

Comment: A circuit diagram is a grossly impractical means of expressing the practical implementation of a decent asynchronous serial receiver - that you would suggest it only confirms that you really have no idea how they actually work, or how systems of non-trivial logic complexity are actually described by engineers. Conversely, a circuit diagram is a silly, but almost practical way to express a transmitter - which is why telling the asker to "invert" their proposal and build a receiver rather than a transmitter is utterly terrible advice.

Comment: The OP is new to this, and at a 555 type of entry level ....do you really want to define the problem as a VHDL solution? That's a rather large step up. That you would consider a logic schematic grossly impractical indicates amazes me.

Comment: No, I want to the OP to stick to something achievable - **such as the transmitter they already chose for themselves**, without getting distracted by your misguidance to build an order of magnitude more complicated receiver instead. But if they're going to do something more complex, then yes, they should **express the algorithm in the easier way with an HDL**, not the absurd way with a schematic - it will already be hard enough for a beginner, there's no reason to make it even more gratuitously difficult by using methods an actual experienced engineer would immediately reject as impractical.

Comment: Then you should definitely educate all of us by providing an answer instead of just grubling about other answers.